# How do I link a node.js webhook to the messenger API of my Facebook app?

Tags: node.js, facebook, heroku, messenger, chatbot

I am unable to link my node.js server as a messenger web hook to my Facebook app. If I try to validate the request in the `'/webhook'` call, Facebook gives me a page not found error while trying to verify and save the web hook. If I place the code in the `'/'` call, that is, `app.get('/',...)` call, I get an internal server error while saving the web hook. My app is hosted on Heroku. On checking the heroic logs, I see this error.

Reference error:

> hub is not defined

and it points to this line:

```
res.send(hub.query['hub.challenge'])
```

My code is:

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var request = require('request')
//the imports

app = express()
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

// Process application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === 'my_voice_is_my_password_verify_me') {
    res.send(hub.query['hub.challenge'])
    }
    res.send('wrong token,error')
})


app.get('/webhook',function(req,res){
    if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === 'my_voice_is_my_password_verify_me') {
    res.send(hub.query['hub.challenge'])
    }
    res.send('wrong token,error')
})


app.listen(app.get('port'), function(req,res) {
    console.log('server running on port',app.get('port'))
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `hub.query` with `req.query` you're trying to access an object that doesn't exist.